# XSLT 2.0: processing nested XSDs

Tags: xslt, import, xsd, nested

I need to collect several XSDs with a (unspecified) number of nested imports into a temporary tree variable. The transformation starts at schema_1.xsd, which in turn imports several other XSDs.

Like this: content of schema_1.xsd:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com" schemaLocation="schema_2.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com" schemaLocation="schema_3.xsd"/>
  <element name="TopElement1">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="ChildElement1"/>
        <element name="ChildElement2"/>
        <element name="ChildElement3"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

and content of schema_2.xsd:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com" schemaLocation="schema_3.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com" schemaLocation="schema_4.xsd"/>
  <element name="TopElement2">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="ChildElement4" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="ChildElement5"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

and so on (I guess including a third XSD is a little redundant?).

What I need to do is to construct an entire temporary tree containing all the nodes from all the nested XSDs, including the content of the first XSD, i.e schema_1.xsd. As can be seen from the XSDs, some imports may occur twice. Preferably, any schema should only be copied to the desired variable once. To make matters worse, I'm aware that there might be cyclic references, which clearly put further constraints on the solution space.

I need the resulting temporary tree to be accessible in a variable in the XSLT. Perhaps like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:variable name="root">
    <!-- magic -->
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- processing $root/fullStructure --> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The actual content of $root I'd like to look something like this:

```
<fullStructure>
  <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com" schemaLocation="schema_2.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com" schemaLocation="schema_3.xsd"/>
    <element name="TopElement1">
      <complexType>
        <sequence>
          <element name="ChildElement1"/>
          <element name="ChildElement2"/>
          <element name="ChildElement3"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
    </element>
  </schema>
  <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com" schemaLocation="schema_3.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com" schemaLocation="schema_4.xsd"/>
    <element name="TopElement2">
      <complexType>
        <sequence>
          <element name="ChildElement4" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="ChildElement5"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
    </element>
  </schema>
  <!-- copy-of for schema_3.xsd and schema_4.xsd is omitted for the sake of brevity. -->
</fullStructure>
```

The size of this tree is only limited by the number of imports and the computational resources available. Of course, the import nodes are not really necessary any more, however, they don't pose a problem either, so a blind copy-of is totally ok.

**Major update**

As requested by Dimitre Novatchev, I've included a couple of valid XSDs, as well as a description of the desired result. In addition, I've removed some superfluous remarks. I have also made some minor updates due to the feedback from LarsH.

Could anyone please give me a pointer in the right direction? Thanks a million!

Comment: This is not difficult, but you need to provide two or three complete XML documents and also the exact wanted result. I would rather not do your job and besides this, there is no guarantee you know what you are asking if you cannot provide this information.

Comment: Thank's Dimitre! I appreciate you taking notice of my question and I fully understand any reluctance of doing someone else's work. :)

Comment: @OP: how are the input XSDs available to us? Is the main XSD filename given as an input parameter to the stylesheet?

Comment: P.S. I guess I should say "XSD filename*s*" (plural).

Comment: @LarsH: oh, sorry about that. I start the transformation at schema_1.xsd. I'll edit the post to make that clear. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:local="http://localhost"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="local xs">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fullStructure>
            <xsl:copy-of select="local:explode(.)"/>
        </fullStructure>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:function name="local:explode" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="pNodes" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="local:explode($pNodes/root(.),())"/>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:function name="local:explode" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="pTodo" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="pDone" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:sequence
             select="if (empty($pTodo))
                     then $pDone
                     else local:explode(
                             document(
                                ($pTodo except $pDone)
                                   /xs:schema/xs:import/@schemaLocation
                             ),
                             $pTodo | $pDone
                          )"/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com"
            schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>
    <element name="TopElement1">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="ChildElement1"/>
                <element name="ChildElement2"/>
                <element name="ChildElement3"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

And this `schema2.xsd` document:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <element name="TopElement2">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="ChildElement4" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="ChildElement5"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Output:

```
<fullStructure>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
        <import namespace="http://www.someplace.com"
                schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>
        <element name="TopElement1">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="ChildElement1"/>
                    <element name="ChildElement2"/>
                    <element name="ChildElement3"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">
        <element name="TopElement2">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="ChildElement4" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="ChildElement5"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
</fullStructure>
```

Comment: Congrats on getting it done. :-) I was working on it, but this looks more elegant than my implementation, albeit similar in approach. Did you test it against multi-level imports with circular references?

Comment: @LarsH: Thanks. To be honest. I didn't test corner cases. I think it should work unless there is something I've missed.

Comment: @Alej: actually the request was to put the `<fullStructure>` tree into a variable called `root`. But that's a trivial change to make.

Comment: FYI, I tested your solution against multi-level imports with circular references, and it worked fine.

Comment: @Alejandro: thank you so much! It works like a charm. As LarsH says, the original request was to fill this in a variable, but that's a no-brainer ... :) I'll study your solution carefully, and can already see that it will teach me much about XSLT/XPath. Thanks again! :) +1